# Workbench - UNKNOWN ERROR: Could not access GitHub tags on Login

Tags: workbench

Good Afternoon,
for some unknown reason our local Workbench instance failed last night and needed to be rebuilt. It is back up to the login page, however when ever you try to log in you get
[image: Unknown Error Could not access Github tags]

I have looked everywhere and can find no information on this.
Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the original configuration of your Workbench instance?

Uncheck "Check for Latest Version" in the configuration. The Workbench source code is hosted on Github and [the application uses a tag URL to check for new releases](https://github.com/forceworkbench/forceworkbench/blob/main/workbench/header.php). (If this check used to work: Does your application run from the same IP? If not, does a firewall block the application from making calls to Github?)

Comment: This worked for me. Specifically I looked for checkForLatestVersion in the defaults.php file and changed
"default" => true,
to
"default" => false,